# Python WebAuthn: Unable to verify attestation statement format

Tags: python, django, webauthn, password-less, attestations

I have implemented some sort of password-less authentication using DUO lab's `webauthn` using Django. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to verify attestation statement format..
```

when authenticating on my Android phone (at least for now).
How can I include more attestation formats to incorporate `Android`, `Windows hello` and any other device in this library's attestation formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the `webauthn` library [only supports the following attestation formats](https://github.com/duo-labs/py_webauthn/blob/4a0f8cd1db3b7635a1951a933d5a690beedf7c50/webauthn/webauthn.py#L49):

- `"fido-u2f"`
- `"packed"`
- `"none"`

You mentioned you're trying to register an Android device - without seeing a response you're getting back from the call to `navigator.credentials.create()` I'd make an educated guess that you're getting responses with `"android-safetynet"` or `"android-key"` attestation statements which the library is unable to verify.

Comment: I actually got `Registration rejected. Unable to verify attestation statement format..` I later found it through the source code that `Android devices` ain't supported yet. Interestingly, some registrations on the same phone were successful.

Comment: If you don't request direct attestation during registration then you're probably getting back "none" formatted attestation statements that verify fine. Just a guess.

Comment: Absolutely, not a even a guess! I wish I could implement verifications for Android statements.

Comment: For those in 2023 or later... your link is for version 0.4.7, and android/apple support was added in 1.0.0.